# inconsistent behavior with jQuery's find()

Tags: jquery, mediaelement.js

Using jQuery 1.7.2. Tested with versions as old as 1.5.1. Same result.

In FF and IE less than 9 it works fine returning the expected jQuery object of DOM elements. However, in everything else it returns a jQuery object of jQuery objects of DOM elements. This screws with anything attempting to get the width or height since those functions in jQuery eventually expect the passed element to be a DOM element (I did a lot of tracing). Also, I have never encountered this problem before. [This is the site where it all went wrong](http://www.commercialsonhold.com). I have not fixed the previous and next buttons yet if you would like to see it in action. It is supposed to call `click()` on the next playlist element. Doesn't because of this issue.

The code is take from [MediaElementJS](http://mediaelementjs.com).

```
t.controls = t.container.find('.mejs-controls');
t.layers = t.container.find('.mejs-layers');
```

The fix I eventually came up with.

```
if(!mf.isFirefox && !(/MSIE [876]/.test(navigator.userAgent))){
    t.controls = t.container.find('.mejs-controls').get(0);
    t.layers = t.container.find('.mejs-layers').get(0);
}else{
    t.controls = t.container.find('.mejs-controls');
    t.layers = t.container.find('.mejs-layers');
}
```

Now, why on God's green earth is it being bad on the new browsers, except FF?

Here are the lines if you want to set-up break-points:

- jquery+mep.js (used to have jQuery bundled in here, took it out for testing)

  - next: 4595
  - previous: 4600
- jquery-1.7.2.js

  - jQuery.next(): 5582
  - jQuery.prev(): 5585
  - jQuery.nth(): 5666

**UPDATE**

Other pages seem unaffected; like http://www.commercialsonhold.com/messagesamples/aesthetics.htm. I am starting to think something else on the page is messing with jQuery. The site is Joomla! I often have trouble with MooTools on Joomla! sites, however, it is normally jQuery not working at all and not just one function acting aberrantly.

**UPDATE**

The jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h5ahY/4/

[image: illustration of the jQuery object in a jQuery object]

Comment: Where is t.container being defined? Can this be replicated in a simple jsfiddle?

Comment: line 1764 `t.container=$('<div id="' + t.id + '" class="mejs-container">'+'<div class="mejs-inner">'+'<div class="mejs-mediaelement"></div>'+'<div class="mejs-layers"></div>'+'<div class="mejs-controls"></div>'+'<div class="mejs-clear"></div>'+'</div>' + '</div>')`

Comment: In the fiddle i'm not getting the same results that you are getting. A jQuery object containing jQuery objects that contain dom elements doesn't make sense, jQuery automatically sanitizes that. http://jsfiddle.net/kxz8v/2/ As you can see on the right, even the last one where i tried to make a jQuery object that contains jQuery objects ended up with a single jQuery object that contains dom elements.

Comment: Which is exactly why it confounds me. In all my traces through both the Chrome debug tools and the IE debug tools, when it got to `t.controls = t.container.find('.mejs-controls');` `t.conrols` would be `jQuery{[0]=jQuery{[0]=DivElement,...},...}` instead of the correct `jQuery{[0]=DivElement,...}`. Adding an update to the question after this. Other pages are unaffected.

Comment: @KevinB Added a picture showing the bizarre result in the Chrome debug tools and a jsFiddle using the original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. It was MooTools. I don't know how and I don't know why.

Fixed by moving the jQuery include above the MooTools include and using `jQuery` instead of `$` everywhere.

Will get a jsFiddle up soon now that I know how to use it now.